# Can we ask question about any language movie and TV?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Can we ask question about any language movie and TV?

Only Hollywood, English?

Or released in English Version?

Comment: Thanks for the good question. I think the answer is yes, but the posts should be in English. I will check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Written text on the SE network is supposed to be in English unless otherwise stated (which only applies to foreign language SEs)

As far as general movie region questions themselves, doing a quick search of the site you can see that we have several questions on Bollywood movies as well as a small few from other movie outlets that are not in english.

If you are asking about differences between, for example, the english version of The Dark Knight vs The Swedish translation, then it is important to note why the difference in the translation has some significance in the question itself, rather than make it sound like a trivia question.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Surely... Can we have tags like Hollywood, Bollywood, Tollywood, Wellywood, or language name for those questions?

Comment: Tags only exist when they are used.  It is impossible to have tags that are not associated with questions.  That said, I believe there are Hollywood and Bollywood tags at the very least.

Comment: Those sort of tags should really only be used when it's relevant.  For example, if we decided that every holylwood movie would have the hoolywood tag, we'd have to retag every batman movie with hollywood.  it wouldn't be very helpful and would make things more difficult.

Comment: What @DForck42 said.  If you want to have a tag for those specific areas, the question would have to pertain to them, not to a movie that happened to be made by them.

Comment: @tyler, So when can we use "too localized" flag in any question in movies.SE?

Comment: @SubirAdhikari Too Localized comes as a few cases on this site.  The most apparent are Identify-This-* questions which are asked by a user then the user abandons the site entirely.  I end up every once in a while going through and purging ones that are bad as TL, The other use for that close reason would be questions about news or current events on TV where the answer could constantly change and doesn't really have a place here to begin with.